# Trivial tangent bundle and orientability

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

> Let $M$ a (real) $n$-dimensional connected differentiable manifold.
>
> **(a)** The tangent bundle $TM$ is trivial, $TM \simeq M \times \mathbb R^n$;
>
> **(b)** $M$ is orientable.
>
> Consider the statements **(a) $\Rightarrow$ (b)**, **(b) $\Rightarrow$ (a)**. Which of them are true?

Well, I'm quite sure **(a) $\Rightarrow$ (b)** is true. What about **(b) $\Rightarrow$ (a)**? I can't believe it is true... in that case we would have **(a) $\Leftrightarrow$ (b)** which seems very strange to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sphere $\rm S^2$ is an orientable manifold, but $\rm TS^2$ is not trivial !

But the contrary is true, a manifold with trivial tangent bundle is orientable.

Comment: I feel so stupid. It was extremely easy, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Manifold is orientable iff its tangent bundle is orientable.

The first Stiefel-Whitney characteristic class of the tangent bundle $TM$( $\omega_1 \in H_1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}))$ is an obstruction to being orientable. That is, $\omega_1 =0$ if $M$ is orientable and the fact is that all of the characteristic classes of trivial bundle are zero, so they are orientable.

So in some sense one can think of nonorientability as twisting in the tangent bundle(existence of Mobius band).